# test checkbox inside a TR table

Tags: jquery

I have an input check-box inside a table TR TD. I trap the click on the TR to do stuff_1, but if I click on the check-box, I would like to do stuff_2 (and not stuff_1):

HTML:

```
<table>
<TR class="tr">
<TD><INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" class="checkbox"></TD>
<TD> Click me 1 to expand</TD>
</TR>

<TR class="tr">
<TD><INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" class="checkbox"></TD>
<TD> Click me 2 to expand</TD>
</TR>
</table>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".tr").click(function(){
  //Here I would like to do STUFF_1

});

$(".checkbox").change(function() {
  //Here I would like to do STUFF_2

});
```

But every time I click on the check-box it does STUFF_1....
How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this :

```
$(".checkbox").click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   // do your stuff
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/vERxc/)

Comment: It also prevents the default action. It might be better to explicitly stop propagation alone, rather than doing both.

Comment: Indeed, the check box does not change state on click if the default action is prevented, at least on Firefox ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/escnf/)).

Comment: @dystroy: Thank you for this useful and practical answer. I'm not a JQUERY man...

Comment: @Frederic Hamidi. I tested it on IE_8 (The project's browser), works fine. But on the current Chrome (version is 23.0.1271.97 m) there is a problem...

Comment: @Zamboo An erroneous version was visible a few minutes. Frederic was right at that time. But I see no problem on Chrome with current version.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$(".tr").click(function(e){
  if(e.target.nodeName == "INPUT") return false;
  // do stuff 1     
});

$(".checkbox").change(function() {
    // do stuff 2    
});
```